# Calculate ellipse parameters from cone second degree equation.

Tags: conic-sections

I'm trying to draw an ellipse basing on cone second degree equation but I have trouble in finding even basic parameters. For example I have the equation

$$1.00 x ^ 2 + -0.60 x y + 0.86 y ^ 2 + -0.29 x + -0.37 y + -0.02 = 0$$

I read [here](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/reference/CRC-formulas/node28.html) that ellipse a and b parameters can be calculated from:

$$a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{A}}$$ 
$$b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{B}}$$

but A and B have to be greater than 0. But Wolfram is dealing with it. Look [HERE](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.00%20x%20%5E%202%20%2B%20-0.60%20x%20y%20%2B%200.86%20y%20%5E%202%20%2B%20-0.29%20x%20%2B%20-0.37%20y%20%2B%20-0.02%20%3D%200). Even if B is less than 0, Wolfram was able to draw ellipse and even name it as ellipse.

So my question is: How I can calculate things from cone second degree equation, especially ellipse $a$, $b$, $\theta$, circuit and surface area?

Comment: $A = 1.00 > 0$ and $B = 0.86 > 0$, so what's the problem? $B$ is the term that multiplies $y^2$, not the one that multiplies $xy$...

Comment: Ohh.. indeed! In other equation i was looking, B was standing next to xy. That solved problem partially. Now i can calculate angle and even center point. But what if ellipse's A and B are both negative? That mean we have an imaginary ellipse. How that could be drawn, like Wolfram is doing it?

Comment: If you have $$-0.4 x^2- 0.9 y^2 = 0$$ is the same as $$0.4 x^2+ 0.9 y^2 = 0$$, right?

Comment: Yes. I have induced that info to my code. But i have still problem determine the equations for theta.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this table of equations:
[Table of equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ0pS.png)

Using those and Matlab I was able to determine each parameter i needed. Thx for helping me with this one :).